# ContextLoader Issue during the starting up of the server

Tags: xml, spring

I am facing the ContextLoader problem during the start up of my server.Below is the log details

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple     ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:174)
     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
```

**Below is the web xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">      

  <context-param>  
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>    
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-  INF/presentationContext.xml /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Spring Application Context</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**Here's My pom**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project>
  <pomVersion>3</pomVersion>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.8</version>
  <url>http://logging.apache.org/log4j/</url>
  <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
  <url>http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/logging/</url>
  <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>xstream</groupId>
  <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
 <url>http://x-stream.github.io/</url>
 <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
 <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
  <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
 <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
 <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
 <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
 <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>bea</groupId>
 <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
 <version>9.1</version>
 <url>http://www.bea.com</url>
 <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 </project>
```

**
Below is the application context xml header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"      
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd         
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="cdqiPerformanceMonitor" class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.aop.interceptor.CDQIPerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />
</beans>
```

Below is the update web.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">      

       <context-param>  
         <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>    
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
         <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-         INF/presentationContext.xml /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml 
        </param-value>
       </context-param>

     <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
      </listener>
      <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Spring Application Context</servlet-name>
     <!-- <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>-->

            <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
            </servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>     
     </servlet>
     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ajax Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tms.cdqi.presentation.ajax.AjaxServlet
           </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>        
     </servlet>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>LoadMasterPreference</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        com.tms.cdqi.presentation.servlet.LoadMasterPrefCatchServlet
        </servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

      <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>CDQIPerformanceFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

       <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>CDQIXScriptingFilter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
       <!-- CCATCS00014750E -  - End -->
       <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>CDQISecurityFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>PresentationApplicationContextFilter
              </filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

         <!--   <welcome-file-list>-->
         <!--       <welcome-file>/index.faces</welcome-file>-->
         <!--   </welcome-file-list>-->

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Ajax Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>LoadMasterPreference</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/presentation/masterCustomerPref</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

     <error-page>
          <error-code>404</error-code>
          <location>/error.jsp</location>
      </error-page>
      <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
            <location>/error.jsp</location>
      </error-page>

        <error-page>
         <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
          <location>/error.jsp</location>
       </error-page>

       <jsp-config>
         <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>http://theserverside.com/customfacescomponents
               </taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/pagination.tld</taglib-location>
       </taglib>
        <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>http://theserverside.com/securityfacescomponents
             </taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/security.tld
             </taglib-location>
         </taglib>
           <!--     <taglib>-->
       <!--<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
                </taglib-uri>-->
        <!--<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>-->
          <!--      </taglib>-->
          <!--      <taglib>-->
            <!--<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions
         </taglib-uri>-->
       <!-- <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fn.tld</taglib-location>-->
    <!--        
  </taglib>-->
   </jsp-config>

   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>
                300
            </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: Remove the `ContextLoaderServlet` that is for old servlet containers (<2.3) which didn't have the listener functionality.

Comment: @Deinum so you mean spring 4 can use its own container? If not do i need to replace with other servlet class?

Comment: No. The `ContextLoaderServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` serve the same purpose only the `ContextLoaderServlet` is for very old servlet containers.

Comment: ContextLoaderServlet has been removed in 2008, so it shouldn't even be in your path. What Spring version are you using? Could you paste here your maven pom/gradle build file to make sure you don't have version conflicts?

Comment: @Deinum , Brain I commented out the context loader servlet .I am getting the error as                                                                                 **User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '2' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'www.springframework.org', port: '80'.**

Comment: I replaced the doc types with the version less xsd as you suggested @M.Deinum

Comment: Please post the header/xml file you are using. Something different why are you specifing the URL and type for all of your dependencies? That shouldn't be necessary, next to that `springframework.org` isn't available anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum pasted the header of the context file

Comment: NIce that you fixed one but looking at your web.xml you have multiple xml files.. Those should all be fixed..

Comment: Could you also paste your full (and updated possible) web.xml...

Comment: @M.Deinum attached the updated web xml also added the same name spaces to the other  xmls present in the web xml

Comment: Make sure that you don't have mixed jars. Looking at the namespace don't add namespaces you don't use (mvc and context). Also the `spring-mvc.xsd` is in `spring-webmvc` which you don't have as a dependency. Either add that as a dependency or remove the xsd.

Comment: @M.Deinum I checked if there are any mix jars and even removed the xsd but still I am facing same problem

Comment: Then I doubt that either the spring version you are using is the one you are actually using (maybe one shipped with WebLogic?) or that the xml isn't the xml as you think you are using. If you are able to use the `ContextLoaderServlet` you are definitly not using Spring 4.1.1 as that has been removed the 3.x branch already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deinum and brain as suggested I removed the context loader servlet and there are two application context xmls being used where I didn't relalized I replaced the doc types with the versionless xsd's .Issue is resolved.